# Why Typescript throws conversion error when trying to perform operation using a function's result?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I'm trying to understand what why Typescript is throwing a type conversion n error when I'm using the results of a function as part of an arithmetic operation.

This probably exemplifies what I'm trying to say.

```js
let foo = ():number => 5
let bar = ():number => 2
let operation = ():number => foo/bar; // The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

```
let baz = foo()
let qux = bar()
let otherOperation = ():number => baz/qux; // no compilation errors
```

Since both `foo` and `bar` are returning type `number`, I'd assume their values could be used as part of an arithmetic operation. Why is that not the case? And how to fix it?

Comment: Run this code in your browser console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug.

`foo` and `bar` are ***functions*** that return a number. They are not numbers themselves.

`foo/bar` doesn't compile because it cannot have a numeric value! That would be like, let's say, dividing the square root by the logarithm. It doesn't make sense to do arithmetic on *the functions themselves*.

Comment: Total brain fart moment (ie. using the function x calling the function). Sorry about that.